Installing SQL Developer in Ubuntu when Java 21 is already installed
I tried to install sqldeveloper Oracle, but it gives the JDK mismatch error. How can I make the settings related to the installation and still use Java 21?
Error :
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
